# How to get string data from a python PIL image object?

Tags: python, file, gif, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to send the data of a gif file of a desktop through a socket to a remote desktop (for desktop sharing) but i can't get the string for the data using PIL, i don't know how to convert the Pil objects to string, here is my code (btw i know i can just write to a file then read the data like that but i think that is inefficient and i think that there is a better way maybe?).

```
    from PIL import ImageGrab
    import cStringIO
    fakie = cStringIO.StringIO()
    ImageGrab.grab().save(fakie, 'GIF')
    data = fakie.getvalue()
    fakie.close()
    # This last bit of code is to see if the var data stored the right info in a str bc i need to send it through a socket
    with open('C:\something\something\Desktop\image.gif', 'w') as f:
        f.write(data)
```

The problem is that after the file is written the gif picture only displays the top 1/10 of the page (the gif file is messed up), and so i'm wondering if the problem lies within my computer or my code (i'm using vista on a VERY old computer, at least 6 years i think and i'm getting a new one soon). Any input is appreciated.

Comment: try open the gif file with "wb" argument.

Comment: What about the `Image.tostring()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @HYRY puts it, you must open the image file  with "wb"  mode instead of "w" - Without the "b" Python defaults to open it in text mode - in windows it means that whenever a 0x0a byte is written to the file, the O.S. writes a 0x0d 0x0a sequence instead, because it translates line ending sequences to Windows native line endings.

In the "wb" mode, there is no translation, and your image file won't be corrupted.